# How does RD_KAFKA_PARTITION_UA work in librdkafka?

Tags: php, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, librdkafka

I have a producer in php which publishes to queue. I am using [php-rdkafka](https://github.com/arnaud-lb/php-rdkafka) library for the same.

Following is the code:

```
        $conf->set('log_level', LOG_DEBUG);
        $conf->set('debug', 'all');
        $rk = new RdKafka\Producer($conf);
        $rk->addBrokers("34.93.118.165:9092");
        $topic = $rk->newTopic("download_first");
        $topic->produce(RD_KAFKA_PARTITION_UA, 0, utf8_encode($message));
        $rk->flush(100);
```

and I have 2 python consumers consuming from the queue.

The topic has 10 partitions. Most of the times when a new message is produced it goes to the same partition as before which is being consumed by a single consumer and as a result other consumer sits idle.

Is there any other partitioner assigning thing I can use while producing messages?

Comment: Have you tried reading the librdkafka documentation on config variables?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yes, all it says is that using the above argument (RD_KAFKA_PARTITION_UA) lets librdkafka decide the partition but doesn't say anything about how

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/arnaud-lb/php-rdkafka uses librdkafka [underneath](https://github.com/arnaud-lb/php-rdkafka/blob/b991173bfc0fe6e6d214e299f82ad1cc74b6e081/topic.c#L528) which is a C based Kafka library.

As per the [docs](https://docs.confluent.io/2.0.0/clients/librdkafka/rdkafka_8h.html#a95e4f88cc907347eee16ff36ab58d10e) RD_KAFKA_PARTITION_UA is for using `automatic partitioning using the topic's partitioner function` or you can pass the exact partition number instead of RD_KAFKA_PARTITION_UA to force a partition.

Or you call `$conf->setPartitioner(RD_KAFKA_MSG_PARTITIONER_RANDOM);` for enabling random partitioner function. [Here's](https://github.com/arnaud-lb/php-rdkafka/blob/78153a64aee4355274db16f7e2f55acb32d7a2d6/conf.c#L807) the list of possible constants for `setPartitioner`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked fine after adding additional configuration ($conf->set('partitioner','random');)